# Express.js: send results after next() is called

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an app that enables users to define their own routes on the fly. And I still want to display an custom 404 message, so in the last middleware I do this:

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  // ...normal logic

  // check for user defined routes 
  next()
  // if res is not written, i.e. request not processed by user defined routes
  if (!res.writableEnded) {
    res.status(404).send(`not found!`)
  }
})
```

However, I got

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for middleware to know if a subsequent route handler is going to pick up the path.

You need to define it last, really last, **after** any user defined routes.

Then you need to *not* call `next()`.